# Xcode 7 massive archive size

Tags: ios

I switched to Xcode 7 and Swift 2. When I was using Xcode 6 my archive size was 70Mb. Now with xCode 7 it looks 200Mb. Is there any solution for resolve this problem?

Ps: I already disabled bitcode

Also how can I see size of libraries in my binary?

Comment: What is you concern with the large archive size? Theses two threads from the apple dev forums say it dosn't matter anymore. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16339, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18365

Comment: I am exporting the archive, my xcode 6 ipa file is 29mb and xcode 7 ipa file is 70mb so It will be 70mb on the app store.

Comment: True, but when it is downloaded to a device, all that extra stuff is stripped away. So what's the problem?

Comment: My ipa file was 29 mb and it was looking 29mb on app store. So new version will be 70mb on app store.